# how to change raster layers style

Tags: openlayers, gis, geo

I want to change raster layers style dynamically according to a value set by the user as we can do with WFS openlayers.I know that WCS is used for raster data but when searched on it, found OpenLayers is a web mapping client, but has no support for WCS (currently).

How would I display and query raster data? Has anyone done this before and can share some experience?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like either

GeoServer http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome
or 
Mapserver http://mapserver.org/

Will enable you to add raster imagery and serve out via WMS which is supported by openlayers and has lots of styling options.

Not sure about mapserver but Geoserver will enable you to pyramid images, cache tiles, get raster data from either oracle or postGis ect wich will help to reduce the performance issues around serving raster data.